# java-The threads in my griddlayout have reversed coordinates

Tags: java, coordinates

I have made a Snake project in which I used a grid layout
with width 20 and height 20. The problem is that when I want to access any square in the panel, it gets  the square with the reversed coordinates. For example: when I use lightMeUp() method, which can change the color of the square, if I choose to color the square with coordinates (1,2) it will color instead (2,1) , and not only that but
other functions inside my project are also affected like this. Like for example when I try to color the positions which are traversed by the snake I have to reverse the coordinates in order to get the right squares colored. I will leave here some code that will show how I built the grid and the threads:

```
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    
    
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame{

    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<DataOfSquare>> Grid;
    public static int width=20;
    public static int height=20;
    public Window() {
        //Creates the arraylist that'll contain the threads
    Grid=new ArrayList<ArrayList<DataOfSquare>>();
        ArrayList<DataOfSquare> data;
        
        //Creates Threads and its data and adds it to the arrayList
        for(int i=0;i<height;i++) {
            data=new ArrayList<DataOfSquare>();
            for(int j=0;j<width;j++) {
                DataOfSquare c=new DataOfSquare(2);
                data.add(c);
            }
            Grid.add(data);
        }
        //Setting up the layout of the panel
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(20,20,5,5));
        //Start and pauses all threads, then adds every square of each thread to the panel
        for(int i=0;i<height;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<width;j++) {
                getContentPane().add(Grid.get(i).get(j).square);
            }
        }
        //initial position of the snake
        Tuple position=new Tuple(5,5);
        //passing this value to the controller
        ThreadsController c=new ThreadsController(position);
        //Let's start the game 
        c.start();
        
        //Links the window to the keyboardListener
        this.addKeyListener((KeyListener) new KeyboardListener());
        
    }
}'
```

I also have other classes inside this project, but I don`t think they have anything to do with this problem so I showed just the code responsible for the grid layout.
There are no errors in my code, the code is doing well if I reverse the coordinates but I just do not understand why it is working like this.
What do I have to do in order to have the coordinates in the right place ?

Comment: Hi&welcome to [so]! 

Comment: Maybe (latest, oracle) [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridLayout.html) can enlighten!? :)